# changing c++ windows code for linux

Tags: c++, linux, winapi

I am working on Linux and need to change given code using win32 api functions into code that can run on linux

```
 bool ret = ::TlsSetValue(tlsInChessFlag, (void *)(((size_t)TlsGetValue(tlsInChessFlag))+1));
```

can some please tell me what could be equivalent code in c++ ubuntu??
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [__thread](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Thread_002dLocal.html) keyword available in GCC (it is a GCC extension).

And to develop C++ code which is portable on both Windows and Linux, you could use some cross-platform library, like e.g. [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use pthreads facilities:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage#Windows_implementation

Answer (score 0):

You could use the boost::thread implementation for [thread local storage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html)

Comment: I don't think you can use Win32 APIs on Linux...

Comment: @rve: oups, you're right - i understood the question the other way - but any way the boost solution is working on both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Use boost's portable thread local API on both Windows and Linux.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html